# How to get Private ip without a third party api in Angular 9

Tags: angular, typescript, ip, angular9

Is there any code to get the private ip of the client in angular 9 without using a third party api? Please help

Comment: I sure hope you can't. No public website has any business knowing my private IP.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/391979/how-to-get-clients-ip-address-using-javascript

Comment: simply not possible